# What is the difference between calling a model on a tensor and evaluate it on data?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, prediction

I am using Tensorflow (and Keras) and I build a model for object recognition.
However when I type

```
sess.run(model(img))
```

and

```
model.predict(img)
```

I obtain two different results.

Should it not be the same?

Below my code results.

```
>>> sess.run(model(img))

array([[[ 14.917048  ,  19.070324  ,  11.41721   , ...,   0.56894594,
           0.49602476,   0.47727835],
        [ 17.025167  ,  17.096733  ,  15.014595  , ...,   0.6136539 ,
           0.44318298,   0.47526497],
        [ 15.252885  ,  16.118824  ,  44.46791   , ...,   0.50266427,
           0.44642642,   0.554879  ],
        ...,
        [411.99896   , 411.99384   ,   1.0055842 , ...,   0.49928427,
           0.5036173 ,   0.49818686],
        [412.00006   , 411.97473   ,   1.6015471 , ...,   0.5021353 ,
           0.50090677,   0.4997861 ],
        [412.01758   , 411.99667   ,   3.269183  , ...,   0.4999951 ,
           0.49951696,   0.49932653]]], dtype=float32)


>>> model.predict(img)
array([[[ 14.59504   ,  17.238186  ,  12.500449  , ...,   0.47316897,
           0.5532172 ,   0.5132638 ],
        [ 14.585468  ,  18.65296   ,  17.775377  , ...,   0.41651973,
           0.4795671 ,   0.47824115],
        [ 16.344007  ,  17.222971  ,  32.62863   , ...,   0.49975312,
           0.42683005,   0.53872365],
        ...,
        [412.03323   , 411.99426   ,   0.9899576 , ...,   0.50225264,
           0.49950108,   0.5034914 ],
        [412.0426    , 411.9642    ,   1.5857234 , ...,   0.5011994 ,
           0.49885157,   0.502774  ],
        [412.01318   , 412.01974   ,   3.302051  , ...,   0.49859652,
           0.49625945,   0.5013649 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Can you include the two results? In what sense are they not the same?